# Formatting options in Webform Select field

Tags: webforms

I have a select field on a webform with 20+ options for the user. The default is a long list of options to select from. Is there any way to have the options broken into columns for the user to choose from so the webform doesn't end up an excessively long form?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) module can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS. Flex or grid

```
#edit-field-event-sponsors-und {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
```

With grid

```
.view-events.view-webinars-archive .view-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  grid-row-gap: 3rem;
```